# NSManagedObjectContext async import, save and notify main context

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have got parent child context as follow: 
1. writercontext with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`
2. mainContext with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` `ParentContext:writercontext`
3. and background context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` `ParentContext:writercontext`

how can i notify the main context with changes made by background context?

i have read [the last part: async save](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) but that doesnt save or import in the background and it gets the UI blocked and unresponsive. is there a way with child parent context in backgound and still notify main context?

currently i save my context:

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    @try {
        NSError *childError = nil;
        if ([context save:&childError])
        {
            [context.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
                NSError *parentError = nil;
                if ([context.parentContext save:&parentError])
                {
                     //saved
                }
                else
                {
                    nslog(@"Error: %@", parentError.description);
                }
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            DBERROR(@"Error: %@", childError.description);
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        DBERROR(@"Exception: %@", exception.description);
    }

}];
```

Comment: any idea guys on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `context` is your background context.
If you call `performBlockAndWait` from the main thread, it will be blocked until the block completes. You should replace your code with:

```
[context performBlock:^{

...

}];
```

That way the main thread won't be blocked, because the block will be executed on another thread.

As for saving, I guess that your changes don't propagate to your `mainContext`. I haven't used nested contexts myself, so I'm not sure why it's working this way (maybe you need to merge changes between contexts manually).